# My MacBook Air is automatically connecting to a password protected network that's not mine!

Tags: wifi, macbook-pro, security

I'm starting to think I've been hacked because my Macbook Air is frequently jumping to a neighbors **password protected** network on its own!

I see the network in the "preferred network" list and I don't know how it got there!  I also don't know what that network's password is but my macbook does!  To make matters worse I've also seen my iPhone on the same network!  Anyone have any ideas as to what's going on?

Comment: Maybe you accidentally  got on their network while they were using WPS to connect another device. Either that or your neighbor broke in and wanted to use her own wifi to get on Facebook for a minute.

Answer (score 7):

Wi-Fi passwords are synchronized via iCloud keychain. That's why your iPhone also knows the password. Try deleting this network from **Preferred Networks**.

Also delete item from your keychain.
In *Keychain Access.app* select iCloud keychain, find the item with the SSID (network name) of your neighbor's network and remove it (Right click -> Remove).

Comment: Thanks for this, but I do have one challenge. The network was not in my Keychain Access.app utility at all.  So the mystery remains as to where my computer is getting the password from. Any thoughts? I was able to remove the network from Preferred Networks and I set require administrator authorization to change networks.